# Create a table with a color background in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I need to modify a report in SSRS 2008 that displays a value using a table representation as follows.

[image]

The accepted value range is 1-7 and the table changes the background color of the cell in the table. I need to be able to modify the color of the color according to some parameter. I reviewd the code and the report was done by creating 7 images -- with the different bachgrounds -- and hiding all images but the one that matches the prarameter value.

I was thinking on using an HTML table to achive this, but the I found out SSRS does not support the table tag. Any ideas on this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I added 7 Textboxes to the report. I aligned them and set the border values and text to look like the image above. Then, set the color property to something similar to this.

```
=IIf(Fields!RangeParameter.Value=2,Parameters!ColorParameter.Value,"Transparent")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up BackgroudColor property of the table cell using expression. In the expression return the proper color code based on your parameter, for instance

> =Switch(Parameters!yourParam.Value=1, "Red", 
>           Parameters!yourParam.Value=2, "Blue"
>           ...)

Comment: It's not chaning the color of the cell according the value of the range. It's changing the color of the given cell (1,2.3,4,,5,6,7) to the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

=iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "#eefafd", "White")